# How to draw squares and assign the color property dynamically (PDFsharp)?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to export a chart legend. I am using a for loop and a table to display the properties. There is actually only one property: the Subdivision name. The object has the right RGB color to use. How can I draw squares next to it just as chart legends display the series? Forgive me for the variable names, I am going off a example.

```
//Writting Table Header Text
textformater.DrawString(" Color", tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoColumn);
textformater.DrawString(" Subdivision Name", tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoStudentName);

foreach (var item in data)
{
    y = y + 30;
    XRect snoColumnVal = new XRect(35, y, 70, height);
    XRect snoStudentNameVal = new XRect(100, y, 250, height);
    textformater.DrawString(item.Color, tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoColumnVal);
    textformater.DrawString(item.Name, tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoStudentNameVal);

}
```

Here is the output:

[image: pdf]

this is what I need it to look like
[image: pic]

Comment: I've lost count of the number of Tile like questions this week. there is a stench of uni/college project submissions... It is a pity you don't give this task a good go yourself, who knows you may actually be good at it.

Comment: i have tried, and I do not know how to dynamically change the color of the object. I wouldnt set a bounty unless I really needed help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this struct for the demo:

```
struct RowItem
{
    public int R, G, B;
    public string Text;
}
```

Here's my test data:

```
var data = new[]
               {
                   new RowItem{R = 255, G = 0, B = 0, Text = "Red row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 0, G = 255, B = 0, Text = "Green row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 255, G = 255, B = 0, Text = "Yellow row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 0, G = 0, B = 255, Text = "Blue row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 255, G = 0, B = 255, Text = "Purple row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 0, G = 255, B = 255, Text = "Cyan row"},
                   new RowItem{R = 0, G = 0, B = 0, Text = "Black row"}
               };
```

And here's the code that does the drawing:

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    y = y + 30;
    XRect snoColumnVal = new XRect(35, y, 60, 25);
    XRect snoStudentNameVal = new XRect(100, y, 250, 25);
    var brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(255, item.R, item.G, item.B));
    gfx.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, brush, snoColumnVal);
    textformater.DrawString(item.Text, font, XBrushes.Black, snoStudentNameVal);
}
```

R, G, and B are the color components (range 0 through 255).

Comment: Use `gfx.DrawRectangle(brush, snoColumnVal);` instead of `gfx.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, brush, snoColumnVal);` if you don't want to have a black frame around the color rectangle.

Comment: `gfx` is the XGraphics object that was also used in the constructor of XTextFormatter.

Comment: so i would need to parse rgb(67,134,215) to R = value, G= value,B=value

Comment: If you have the colour values in a string then you will have to parse them.

Answer (score 2):

Just draw the square like so:

```
// Create solid brush.
SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

// Create rectangle.
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);

// Fill rectangle to screen.
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rect);
```

Here is how you set the color:

```
// Create a green color using the FromRgb static method.
Color myRgbColor = new Color();
myRgbColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
return myRgbColor;
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so I would put the color code inside the loop? item.color would replace (0,255,0)  I assume e.Graphics would be xGraph.Graphics if I have   XGraphics xGrap = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfpage);    If so then xGraph is not picking up Graphics in intellesense

Comment: This answer shows how to draw rectangles on the screen using C# and GDI+. The classes used by PDFsharp are similar, but slightly different (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

To draw squares, use `DrawRectangle` instead of `DrawString`.

Sample code can be found here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_rectangles_6

The Graphics sample is also included in the PDFsharp source package.